# Shipping calculator not showing correct price

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program in C that is a shipping calculator, which calculates the shipping price. The program would work as follows. First, the user would type the weight in pounds and the distance in miles. The program then reports to the user how much he or she should pay for the shipping based on the number of pounds and shipping. If I type the weight at 1.5 pounds and distance in miles that is more than 0 miles but less than or equal to 500 miles, the price shows up correctly, which is $3. However, if the weight is more than 10 pounds and less than or equal to 50 pounds, instead of the price showing up as $5, it still shows up at $3. This issue does not only occur when I type the number of pounds, but also when I type the distance. For instance, if I type 5 pounds and then type 700 miles, the shipping price still shows up at $3 instead of $6. I have researched online to see where the problem could be but no luck, unfortunately. The code for the program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

double packageWeight, packdistanceMiles,packPrice, totalPrice;


printf("Please enter package weight: ");
scanf("%lf", &packageWeight);
printf("The package weight is: %.2lf \n", packageWeight);
system("pause");
printf("Please enter how far the package will be sent in miles: ");
scanf("%lf", &packdistanceMiles);
printf("The distance entered in miles is: %.2lf \n", packdistanceMiles);
system("pause");




if(packdistanceMiles==0)

    printf("You must enter a distance that is more than zero, close the program and try again \n");

else
   
if(packageWeight>50)
            
printf("Sorry, we do not ship packages that weight more than 50 pounds");
   
if(packageWeight>0 || packageWeight <=10)
             packPrice = 3.00;
    
if(packageWeight>10 || packageWeight <=50)
             packPrice = 3.00;
else

   
if(packdistanceMiles>0 || packdistanceMiles <=500)
        totalPrice = packPrice;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>500 || packdistanceMiles <=1000)
        totalPrice = 2* packPrice;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>1000 || packdistanceMiles <=1500)
        totalPrice = (2* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>1500 || packdistanceMiles <=2000)
        totalPrice = (3* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>2000 || packdistanceMiles <=2500)
        totalPrice = (4* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>2500 || packdistanceMiles <=3000)
        totalPrice = (5* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>3000 || packdistanceMiles <=3500)
        totalPrice = (6* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>3500 || packdistanceMiles <=4000)
        totalPrice = (7* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>4000 || packdistanceMiles <=4500)
        totalPrice = (8* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>4500 || packdistanceMiles <=5000)
        totalPrice = (9* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>5000 || packdistanceMiles <=5500)
        totalPrice = (10* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>5500 || packdistanceMiles <=6000)
        totalPrice = (11* packPrice)+10;

       
printf("The shipping price is %.2lf \n", packPrice);
       
system("pause");


return 0;



}
```

Comment: So why don't you debug it? That's what needs to be done when one finds their program doesn't work. Run your program in a debugger and step through it line by line, examining the state as it runs.

Comment: Why gcc, codeblocks and visualstudio tags? Your question is not related to it

Comment: Comparing floats to literal values with `==` is asking for trouble. Due to artifacts of the floating point format you may get close but not *quite* matching results.

Comment: here you have online debugger: https://onlinegdb.com/S1C-JTEOD

Comment: format your code. In this form, it is not possible to read

Comment: All your `||`'s should be `&&`'s

Comment: For the second `else` why is it in the code at that spot? Doesn't look right. Suggest you check that.

Comment: `packPrice = 3.00;` under BOTH conditions.... (copy/paste error). Additionally the `else` on its own looks suspect.

Comment: Problem solved! When I changed the ||'s to &&'s, the program now works perfectly.

Comment: @FelipeXavierDiaz Please consider reviewing a style guideline before submitting next time.  C is a wonderful language that will let you do pretty much anything you want.  On the other hand, C pretty much let's you do anything you want so it is very easy to obfuscate code.  Brackets and indentation would go a long way to indicating intention. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say distance is 700 miles:

```
if(packdistanceMiles>0 || packdistanceMiles <=500)
        totalPrice = packPrice;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>500 || packdistanceMiles <=1000)
        totalPrice = 2* packPrice;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>1000 || packdistanceMiles <=1500)
        totalPrice = (2* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>1500 || packdistanceMiles <=2000)
        totalPrice = (3* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>2000 || packdistanceMiles <=2500)
        totalPrice = (4* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>2500 || packdistanceMiles <=3000)
        totalPrice = (5* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>3000 || packdistanceMiles <=3500)
        totalPrice = (6* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>3500 || packdistanceMiles <=4000)
        totalPrice = (7* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>4000 || packdistanceMiles <=4500)
        totalPrice = (8* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>4500 || packdistanceMiles <=5000)
        totalPrice = (9* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>5000 || packdistanceMiles <=5500)
        totalPrice = (10* packPrice)+10;
   
if(packdistanceMiles>5500 || packdistanceMiles <=6000)
        totalPrice = (11* packPrice)+10;
```

Then, execution will enter on 2º If, 3º If, 4º If, ... because distance < 1000 and distance < 1500 and distance < 2000. Consider using else if instead if.

Comment: Or maybe change or operator to and operator

Answer (score 0):

There's really no reason for all of that code. It can boil down to something much simpler if you *just do the math*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double shippingCalc(double packageWeight, double packdistanceMiles) {
  double packPrice = 3.0;

  // These calculations seem pointless, but maybe they will take on different
  // values in the future.
  if (packageWeight >= 0 || packageWeight <= 10) {
    packPrice = 3.00;
  }
  else if (packageWeight > 10 || packageWeight <= 50) {
    packPrice = 3.00;
  }

  double totalPrice = (int) (packPrice / 500);

  // Some kind of surcharge for > 1000 miles?
  if (packdistanceMiles > 1000) {
    totalPrice += 10;
  }

  return totalPrice;
}
```

Where now you can call this function from the `main()` function:

```c
int main () {
  double packageWeight, packdistanceMiles;

  printf("Please enter package weight: ");
  scanf("%lf", &packageWeight);
  printf("The package weight is: %.2lf \n", packageWeight);
  system("pause");
  printf("Please enter how far the package will be sent in miles: ");
  scanf("%lf", &packdistanceMiles);
  printf("The distance entered in miles is: %.2lf \n", packdistanceMiles);
  system("pause");

  if (packdistanceMiles <= 0) {
    printf("You must enter a distance that is more than zero, close the program and try again \n");
    return -1;
  }
  else if (packageWeight > 50) {
    printf("Sorry, we do not ship packages that weight more than 50 pounds");
    return -1;
  }

  printf("The total price is %.2lf \n", shippingCalc(packageWeight, packdistanceMiles));

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Whenever possible try and break up your code into easier to understand *functions* with well-defined *inputs and outputs* as well as a singular, well-defined *responsibility*.